# How to create and configure MariaDBDataSource manually

Tags: java, jdbc, mariadb

I'm having problems with creating unpooled datasource with MariaDBDataSource class.

```
MariaDbDataSource mysqlDs = new MariaDbDataSource(connectionUrl);
mysqlDs.setPassword(password);
mysqlDs.setUser(username);
return wrapWithPool(mysqlDs);
```

wrapWithPool simply wraps the given datasource with a pooled one (c3p0 pool).
But I fail to checkout a connection from the pool. Whenever I do

```
datasource.getConnection()
```

I get

```
org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.dao.QueryException: Could not connect: Access denied for user 'someuser'@'somehost' (using password: NO)
```

Not sure why? I do set non empty password. Is there anything else to set on the MariaDbDatasource class to make it use the password?

edit:
Ok, so it seems that when I do not wrap the MariaDbDataSource all works ok.
So c3p0 is breaking up the connection, and from debug I see it fails to get the password...
The wrap method is quite simple

```
private static DataSource wrapWithPool(DataSource unpooled) throws SQLException {
            unpooled.setLoginTimeout(HOST_REACH_TIMEOUT.getValue());
            Map<String, Object> poolOverrideProps = new HashMap<>();
            poolOverrideProps.put("maxPoolSize", CONNECTION_POOL_SIZE.getValue());
            poolOverrideProps.put("minPoolSize", 1);
            poolOverrideProps.put("checkoutTimeout", HOST_REACH_TIMEOUT.getValue() * 2);
            return DataSources.pooledDataSource(unpooled, poolOverrideProps);

        }
```

And it works perfecly fine with other drivers (oracle, jtds). Why not with mariaDb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I discovered the problem. For some reason, the c3p0 when creating the pool, wraps the given DataSource class within own WrapperConnectionPoolDataSourceBase class. Then it tries to detect the authentication parameters from it using reflection. Since MariaDBDataSource does not provide the getPassword method, the discovered value is null, and thus the error message about not using the password.

So as a workaround I did a simple wrapper

```
private static class MariaDbDExtender extends MariaDbDataSource {

        private String password;

        public MariaDbDExtender(String connectionUrl) throws SQLException {
            super(connectionUrl);
        }


        @Override
        public void setPassword(String pass) {
            this.password = pass;
            super.setPassword(pass);
        }

        //this method is required to allow c3p0 magically use reflection to get correct password for connection
        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }
    }
```

and later on

```
MariaDbDExtender mysqlDs = new MariaDbDExtender(connectionUrl);
mysqlDs.setPassword(password);
mysqlDs.setUser(username);
return wrapWithPool(mysqlDs);
```

And it magically starts to work. This is some driver specific issue, since oracle datasource does not have the getPassword method, but works. So some very specific implementation details of those 2 libraries just make it incompatible in my use case.